# Código para aba / janela / guia do browser piscar

Tags: javascript, alert, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde, como não sou bom em javascript, então preciso dos mestres aqui para me ajudar. Estou montando um sistema via browser para uma empresa. Nesse sistema acontecerá vários eventos, e como escrevi no título, preciso de um código para que quando o usuário receba uma nova mensagem de algum evento ocorrido, a aba do navegador fique piscando.

Sei que posso fazer isso com `alert` do javascript (acredito eu), e se tiver que fazer dessa forma, gostaria de algo simples, e que sumisse quando o usuário abrisse aquela janela que está piscando.

Encontrei um exemplo no stackoverflow da "gringa" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381462/how-to-create-the-title-alert-effect-like-facebook, que atende, em partes, esta necessidade, pois ele fica alterando o título e isso chama a atenção do usuário. Mas gostaria que houvesse uma forma de piscar, se existir, claro.

Segue o código que encontrei:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {

    var original = document.title;
    var timeout;

    window.flashTitle = function (newMsg, howManyTimes) {
    function step() {
    document.title = (document.title == original) ? newMsg : original;

    if (--howManyTimes > 0) {
        timeout = setTimeout(step, 1000);
      };
    };

    howManyTimes = parseInt(howManyTimes);

    if (isNaN(howManyTimes)) {
       howManyTimes = 5;
    };

    cancelFlashTitle(timeout);
    step();
    };

    window.cancelFlashTitle = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.title = original;
  };

  }());

  </script>
```

Sugestões são muito bem vindas.

Obrigado

Comment: Amigo acredito que você não conseguirá fazer o efeito que pretende.
Uma dica é utilizar as notificações em desktop, de uma olhada neste plugin [https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications](https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications). Uma vez que o usuário permite as notificações, ele começa a receber as mensagens no desktop mesmo com o navegador minimizado. Eu utilizo desta forma e meus usuários gostaram. Vou procurar outros plugins, se souber de algo posto pra você.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
    var titulo = "- Teste -"
    var titulo = titulo + "          " 
    i = "0"
    var tmptitulo = "" 
    var velocidade = "50"
    const scrollTitulo = () => {

    if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
        return

    document.title = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    tmptitulo = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    i++
    if (i == titulo.length)
    {
        i = "0"
        tmptitulo = ""
    }
    setTimeout("scrollTitulo()", 35)
}

window.onload = scrollTitulo
```